# Cannot use npm or Yarn. Timeout errors, crypto errors, aaaaargh

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, openssl

I have an empty directory open in VSCode. I try to create a react app and the terminal just freezes. I cannot install any packages. npm and yarn both end with the same error:

```
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT 
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to http://registry.npmjs.org/creat-react-app failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700::6810:1223:80
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\fluva\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-04-28T03_27_08_973Z-debug-0.log
```

I WAS able to run `npm init -y`

I tried to open another app in VSCode and it gave me this error:

```
Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
```

to which I used: `$env:NODE_OPTIONS = "--openssl-legacy-provider"` - I then ran yarn start and the app ran.

So, right now, I cant create any new React apps and when i am in the React app that is running, I am not able to install any new packages. It will usually freeze at this:

```
| idealTree:tryagain: sill idealTree buildDeps
```

There is NO Proxy. There is no Firewall interference as far as I can tell. I disabled all security to test and got the same results. I have uninstalled Node, and reinstalled. I have uninstalled Openssl and reinstalled 1.1.1.

node
v18.16.0

npm
9.6.0

openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1t  7 Feb 2023

yarn -v
1.22.19

Windows 10

XXXXXXX - PS - XXXXXXX
This is all on my desktop. The key factor here is that it is also happening on my laptop. So I figure it to be a network issue??? Frustrated!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a weak network connection, you may get a timeout error when downloading large packages like `react`. Try adding a `.npmrc` file in your project directory and add this setting:

```js
timeout=120000 // or even higher if you have terrible connection
```

Then try to install your packages.